# What are the differences between the legacy installer and the regular installer?

Tags: system-installation, 23.10

The Desktop release of Ubuntu 23.10 was recently retracted [due to a malicious translation contribution](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/announcement-ubuntu-desktop-23-10-release-image-is-being-updated-to-resolve-a-malicious-translation-incident/39365). However, the "Legacy Desktop Installer" is still available.

What are the differences between the legacy installer and the regular installer? Are there any downsides to using the legacy installer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old installer (Legacy installer) used `Ubiquity` the new version uses `Flutter` which is intended to be a much improved version to the, some say, tired version which has been around for a long time.

There are no disadvantages to using the old version which will leave you with the same Ubuntu system once the install is finished.

[reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/178e0f2/what_is_the_difference_between_normal_ubuntu_2310/)

Comment: The legacy installer is still subject to launchpad bug 1396379 -- Grub installs to wrong disk.  An install to a second disk will leave the second disk with an empty EFI partition, and the host unbootable without the second disk. The Subiquity installer in 23.04 fixed this -- don't know what the Flutter installer does.